# Find the number of repetitions of a character in a given string and sort them?

Tags: java, collections

**Problem statement:** Find the repetition of the alphabet characters in a given string (all lower case from a-z only) and sort them from lowest to highest.
If two character have the same number of repetitions, the character with the greater ASCII value is considered to be smaller.

Although the problem is easy, I was trying to use Comparator to sort the final answer instead of using my own sorting. Here is what I did:

```
    private static void importantString(String context) {
        HashMap<Character, Integer> importance = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
        String alpha="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        for(int i=0; i<26; i++){
            importance.put(alpha.charAt(i),0);
        }
        for(int i=0; i<context.length(); i++){
            char temp = context.charAt(i);
            Integer val = importance.get(temp);
            importance.put(temp,++val);
        }

        //To sort
        ArrayList<Map.Entry<Character, Integer>> l = new ArrayList(importance.entrySet());
        Collections.sort(l, new Comparator<Map.Entry<Character, Integer>>(){
             public int compare(Map.Entry<Character, Integer> o1, Map.Entry<Character, Integer> o2) {
                if (o1.getValue()==o2.getValue()){
                    if (o1.getKey() > o2.getKey()){
                        return -1;
                    }
                    else{
                        return 1;
                        }

                }
                else {
                return o1.getValue().compareTo(o2.getValue());
                }
            }});
        System.out.println(l);
        for (Entry<Character, Integer> m: l){
            System.out.print(m.getKey()+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
}
```

Now, this definitley works for smaller test cases. For example,

However, I had a very large test case this is what I get (my sorted array is this since the test case string is very large):

```
[r=38083, p=38223, v=38223, f=38268, e=38269, u=38306, z=38320, k=38341, g=38342, c=38396, o=38418, q=38418, b=38422, n=38467, x=38476, y=38477, l=38525, m=38534, w=38575, d=38580, a=38619, s=38648, t=38653, h=38787, j=38791, i=38839]
```

Notice, o=38418 and q=38418. In this case 'q' should have a lower precedence than o since it has a higher ASCII value. Yet it does not reflect.

For smaller test cases like oooqqq, I do get the correct results. Any explainations why?

Comment: Talking about ASCII in a modern programming environment leads to [programming by coincidence](https://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/coincidence). To address the requirement to sort by ASCII values, you at least need a comment that `charAt` returns a UTF-16 code unit, that UTF-16 encodes each of the expected input characters as one UTF-16 code unit so its value is the same as the Unicode codepoint, that Unicode includes all the ASCII characters and has the same codepoints for them, so sorting by `char` for the expected input is the same as sorting by ASCII.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is this line:

```
if (o1.getValue()==o2.getValue()){
```

You're using reference equality here. Since both sides of `==` are of type `Integer`s they are tested for reference equality, but only for values `-128 <= value <= 127` those `Integer`s are guarantied to be the same objects (see [`Integer.valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf-int-) which is used for autoboxing here: `importance.put(temp,++val);`)

You could simply replace this with a comparison of the int values:

```
if (o1.getValue().intValue()==o2.getValue().intValue()){
```

Furthermore you could also rewrite the method by using `Integer.compareTo` and `Character.compareTo`:

```
public int compare(Map.Entry<Character, Integer> o1, Map.Entry<Character, Integer> o2) {
    int res = o1.getValue().compareTo(o2.getValue());
    return res == 0 ? o2.getKey().compareTo(o1.getKey()) : res;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you don't have the "equal" case in your comparator for letters, also the Integer class should be compared using `equals`, not `==.`

Change the `Comparator` and sorting part to something like this:

```
           Collections.sort(l, new Comparator<Map.Entry<Character, Integer>>(){
             public int compare(Map.Entry<Character, Integer> o1, Map.Entry<Character, Integer> o2) {
                if (o1.getValue().equals(o2.getValue())){
                    return -o1.getKey().compareTo(o2.getKey()))                          
                }
                else {
                    return o1.getValue().compareTo(o2.getValue());
                }
            }});
```

Comment: You could save one negation: `-o1.getKey().compareTo(o2.getKey()))` = `o2.getKey().compareTo(o1.getKey()))`